# IP Canonicalization for website hosted on CPanel

Tags: .htaccess, seo, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

I have hosted my website using WHM and Cpanel, 
and added following lines to .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^103\.241\.144\.130
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.rockinexams.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

now, this:

```
http://103.241.144.130/~rockinex/
```

redirects to www.rockinexams.com but 103.241.144.130 does not. 
I heard that this does not work due to something related to cpanel architecture. 
Is there any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If that IP is a shared IP, your rule will not work. For this rule work, you need a Dedicated IP to access just http:YOUR-IP. You even can try to put the ~rockinex on rule, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Its not shared IP, I have VPS. So the given IP is dedicated for my website.

Comment: But this IP is set as a Dedicated IP for your website or that's your cPanel main IP? Because if is the cPanel main IP, this IP is the shared IP for all cPanel accounts.

Comment: This is cPanal main IP, so you are correct that it will be shared for all cPanal accounts. So no way to get around it?

Comment: If you don't have a secondary IP for make as a Dedicated IP, your only attempt is put ~rockinex on .htacces rule.

Comment: Ok, let me try this. will inform the results.

Comment: Waiting the results :)

Comment: Yeah. :) Some or other person is always accessing the site, trying to find out slot when I can restart the services. :). Will definitely  inform. :)

Comment: Is this correct: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ~rockinex
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.rockinexams.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that's right. Maybe you could try RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/~rockinex

Comment: Just tried the one I mentioned earlier. it did not work. I think even when we try the one you stated above, it would be same as IP/~rockinex, which is already working, please correct me if I missed something.

Comment: The best way to solve this is assign a dedicated IP for this account on cPanel.